# Fortran goto legacy error

Tags: gcc, fortran

I am wondering how is it possible to make the first loop being repeated if it does not meet the `if` condition. While I have been trying to use the `goto` statement it gives me the legacy error. How can I fix that?

```
   10   do i=0,izmax
         some code
          do j=jmin,jmax
           some other code
          enddo
        enddo

    do i=0,izmax
      if (x < y) then
        write 
      else goto 10
    enddo
```

In other case, when only one thing from the loop should be repeated what is the method? By that I mean

```
     do i=0,izmax
         some code
          do j=jmin,jmax
           some other code
          enddo
  10 statement to be repeated
        enddo

    do i=0,izmax
      if (x < y) then
        write 
      else goto 10
    enddo
```

Comment: Put the loop in a subroutine and call that.

Comment: That helps me a lot :) But in other case, when I would only need the one statement outside of the second loop to be repeated what should have I dont then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notdone=.true.
do while(notdone)
 do i=0,izmax
    first loop
 enddo
 notdone=.false.
 do i=0,izmax
  if (x < y) then
    write 
  else
    notdone=.true.
    exit !exits inner loop
  endif      
 enddo 
enddo
```

Comment: Thank You so much, that is the answer I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named loop, set it to execute continuously, but have an `exit` statement at the end. Then you can, if you need to, `cycle` that outer loop before you reach the end.

```
outer : do
    do i = 0, izmax
        ! First Loop
    end do
    do i = 0, izmax
        if (x < y) then
            write(*, *) "Need to do again"
            cycle outer
        end if
    end do
    exit outer
end do outer
```

Your second question is much harder to understand. What should the program do after it has done the `statement to be repeated` again. Should it again go into that loop? Should it immediately exit the first loop and restart the second?

I think it might be easier to just repeat the statement, or place it inside a subroutine to be called from inside the first loop and from where it needs to be executed again.